# How and why hamster.stomach changes while hamster.legs staying same

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I am fairly new to oop in js. I know the basics of **proto** and prototype but I am not sure my problem is causing from them. I also dig into this keyword cant find anything solution-kindly. Anyways my code is here.(Normally I would expect change at only speedy object but I read somewhere that hamster.stomach changes, still dont really know the reason tho, so my question is why hamster.stomach changes and why hamster.legs is not.)

````
let hamster = {
  stomach: [],
    legs: 4,
  change_leg(n){this.legs = n;},
  eat(food) {
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
};

let speedy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

let lazy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

// This one found the food
speedy.eat("apple");
speedy.change_leg(10);
alert( speedy.stomach ); // apple
alert(speedy.legs);
alert(hamster.legs);
alert( hamster.stomach ); // apple```
````

Comment: `change_leg` mutates the `speedy` object, not the `hamster` and not the `lazy` one. In contrast, `eat` does mutate the `.stomach` array - the single, shared array being referenced thrice.

Comment: @Bergi so, it is caused by the characteristic of array right. If there is an string property or boolean etc. those wont be changed too.

Comment: Yes, the array is a mutable object on its own.